# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges with Respawn and Oracle database

Tags: oracle, docker, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automated-tests

I'm trying to use [Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn/) to reset the database between each test in an Oracle database.

While Entity Framework works just fine, I'm getting a `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException` with message `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` when executing `respawner.ResetAsync(dbConnection);` with the same connection string.

I don't know if this is a Respawn issue or an oracle configuration issue, but I don't know how to debug this because the exception does not contain the specific SQL statement that is causing the permissions issue.

I'm starting the database with docker compose with the following file:

```yaml
version: "3.1"

services:
  oraclesql:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise
    container_name: oracle-sql1
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
    environment:
      ORACLE_SID: Respawn
      ORACLE_PDB: Respawn1
      ORACLE_PWD: PasswordO1.
    volumes:
      - ./env/oracle/setup:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup:ro #Configures test_user
```

The user is configured on startup of the database in the docker container with the following sql:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = Respawn1;
CREATE USER test_user IDENTIFIED BY "some-password";
GRANT CONNECT TO test_user CONTAINER=CURRENT;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO test_user CONTAINER=CURRENT;
GRANT RESOURCE TO test_user CONTAINER=CURRENT;
ALTER USER test_user QUOTA 100M ON USERS;
```

And the issue can be reproduced with the following C# code:

```cs
var connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=Respawn1)));User Id=test_user;Password=some-password";
using var dbContext = new AppDbContext(connectionString);
using var dbConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
await dbConnection.OpenAsync();
var respawner = await Respawner.CreateAsync(dbConnection, new RespawnerOptions
{
    DbAdapter = DbAdapter.Oracle,
});
await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
dbContext.Entities.Add(new Entity
{
   Name = "An Entity Name",
});
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
await respawner.ResetAsync(dbConnection); //This line produces the exception
```

Anyway, I have uploaded a repo with this complete example [here](https://github.com/dgarciarubio/RespawnOracleExample)

Comment: I think you have to grant to testing user sufficient privileges [ORA-01031: insufficient privileges tips](https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01031_insufficient_privileges.htm). It depends what respawned do with database.